# How to display half hour ticks on x-axes

Tags: chart.js

I have a record with data from the last 36 hours. These should be displayed in my Chart.js -Chart so that there is a tick every 30 minutes. If a data set falls on xx:45, it should not be rounded to the 30-minute interval.

I have the feeling that I have not yet understood the terms ticks and units correctly. I want to have vertical lines every 30 minutes, but the data sets should be freely distributed on the x-axis.

```
{
...
   type: "time",
   time: {
       unit: "minute",
       displayFormats: {
           minute: "HH:mm"
       },
       stepSize: 30
   },
   gridLines: {
       drawOnChartArea: true,
       color: ["transparent", ...Array(Math.max(0, countDays(bedCapacities) - 2)).fill("#DFF2FA"), "#303740"],
       zeroLineColor: "#DFF2FA",
       drawBorder: true,
       tickMarkLength: -20
   },
   ticks: {
       fontColor: "#CCCCCC",
       fontSize: 11,
       fontStyle: "bold",
       labelOffset: 20,
       source: "auto"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my setting, using v3.6.0.
You can ignore y axis, just let you know mine works.

```
scales: {
        x: {
          type: 'time',
          time: {
            unit: 'minute',
            stepSize: 30
          },
          min: tradingDuration().openTime,
          max: tradingDuration().closeTime
          // title: {
          //   display: true,
          //   text: 'Date'
          // }
        },
        y: {
          min: limitDown,
          max: limitUp
        }
      },
```

Comment: It seems like he is using V2 while your answer is in V3 syntax, might want to change it to be more relevant